# Double linked list2

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, structure

I did a lot of linked lists already,
but I didn't use them for a while and didn't really programm anything, therefore I am litterally lost.
The following is my Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int age; 
    int pers_num;
    char name[100];
    void *previous;
    void *next;
    
}Person;

int main(){
    Person first_element;
    Person last_element;
    first_element.next = (Person *)(&last_element);
    last_element.age = 19;
    printf("%d\n",(&last_element)->age);
    printf("%d\n",(first_element.next)->age);
    
    }
```

Could you explain to me why following error is thrown?

```
speicher.c: In function 'main':
speicher.c:22:39: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer
   23 |     printf("%d\n",(first_element.next)->age);
      |                                       ^~
speicher.c:23:39: error: request for member 'age' in something not a structure or union
```

As I understand it "first_element.next" should be the pointer which points at last_element.
therefore you should be able to use the -> to access the data inside last_element.
The line 22 Runs perfectly even thought it should have the same Output as line 23, where the error is thrown.

Comment: You need to cast it. Like `((Person*) first_element.next)->age`.

Comment: Why use `void *` pointers for the links? Try e.g. `typedef struct Person { /* ... */ struct Person *previous; struct Person *next; } Person;` and you don't need the cast.

Answer (score 2):

You can't dereference a void pointer because it's a pointer that references a void type :-) In other words, it doesn't really *know* what actual type it points at. The reason why the two lines behave differently are, keeping in mind that `a->b` is just syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`:

```c
printf("%d\n",(&last)->age);
    // This (&last)->age, which is actually the same
    // as last.age. In both cases, the type being used
    // to get the age field is Person, so no problem.

printf("%d\n",(first.next)->age);
    // This (first.next)->age is the same as
    // (*(first.next)).age. Because first.next is of type
    // void *, it cannot be dereferenced.
```

What you are doing is akin to declaring a variable with `void x`, which is not valid (don't confuse that with `void *x` which is valid).

You would be better off (within the structure) pointing to the *actual* type you want, with something like:

```c
typedef struct s_Person { // A
    int age; 
    int pers_num;
    char name[100];
    struct s_Person *previous, *next;
} Person; // B
```

Note that you *cannot* use the `Person` type definition while you're creating it, since it does not yet exist. Simplistically, you can think of it coming into existence at the `B` point. The named structure `s_Person` comes into existence at `A` so it *can* be used within the structure.